# AttributedString/Substring extension: Cannot assign through dynamic lookup property: subscript is get-only

Tags: swift

If I have the following:

```swift
let nsRange = NSRange(location: 5, length: 10)
var attributedString = AttributedString("This is some string that I want to attribute.")
// To attribute a substring I must first convert the range
let start = attributedString.index(attributedString.startIndex, offsetByUnicodeScalars: nsRange.location)
let end = attributedString.index(start, offsetByUnicodeScalars: nsRange.length)
// Now we have a Range<AttributedString.Index>
let range = start..<end
attributedString[range].foregroundColor = .red
```

^ This code works ^

But if I try to remove some boilerplate by creating a subscript as follows:

```swift
extension AttributedString {
  subscript(_ range: NSRange) -> AttributedSubstring {
    get {
      let start = index(startIndex, offsetByUnicodeScalars: range.location)
      let end = index(start, offsetByUnicodeScalars: range.length)
      return self[start..<end]
    }
  }
}
```

```swift
attributedString[nsRange].foregroundColor = .red
```

^ this doesn't work ^

I get a `Cannot assign through subscript: subscript is get-only` error. But I'm confused why. `attributedString[nsRange]` return an `AttributedSubstring`, and `AttributedSubstring`  can have properties set with the `.foregroundColor = .red` syntax. It works with a `Range<AttributedString.Index>` like `str[start..<end].foregroundColor = .red` so why not with my subscript?

Comment: Look at your `subscript` code, there is only `get`, this is what the error is telling you.

Comment: @vadian because my code is only extending `AttributedString`. My extension subscript returns an `AttributedSubstring`, not an `AttributedString`, so a subscript setter would not do anything, as I'm not trying to change an `AttributedString` at that point in the code.

Comment: Please edit; it is confusing to see "This code works" when it does not. I think maybe if you got it to work, then you wouldn't have a question…very confusing why you'd think it wasn't what Asperi answers with!

Comment: @Jessy I have updated the `let` to a `var`, so you can get your knickers out of a twist, but that still doesn't make work what I'm looking for. That only fixes my original code that I had working, it doesn't fix my subscript.

Comment: My expectations are already low, but I can't believe how terrible Apple's documentation is on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only wrote a getter for the subscript. You also need a setter if you want to write through it (as the error notes):

```
    set {
        let start = index(startIndex, offsetByUnicodeScalars: range.location)
        let end = index(start, offsetByUnicodeScalars: range.length)
        self[start..<end] = newValue
    }
```

The point that Asperi is making is that the returned struct is a copy (this is true in the example you give from the docs as well). These examples are very different:

```
// This modifies a *copy* of `value`. It does *not* modify `xs`.
// It calls the subscript getter of `xs`.
var value = xs[i]
value.prop = "newThing"

// This modifies `xs`:
// It calls the subscript setter of `xs`.
xs[i].prop = "newThing"
```

Comment: Thank you. I got it working with: `set(val) {
      self[val.startIndex..<val.endIndex] = val
    }`.  It was confusing at first because `attributedString[range]` returns a substring, so I was confused how a setter on AttributedString would make the `.foregroundColor = .red` part work. I appreciate the helpful response.

Comment: Swift value types can sometimes be tricky because the language has various helpers that make things easier, but in a misleading way. Writing through setters can give the illusion that you're modifying a reference, but what really happens is that a copy of the element is made, you modify the copy, **a copy of the entire collection is made that replaces the old element with the new element**, and then the entire collection is assigned back to the original variable. (There are optimizations that get rid of some literal copying, but logically this is what happens.)

Comment: They are tricky for sure. I'm used to dealing with value types in FP, but the mixing of value/reference types in Swift can be confusing.  Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

`AttributedString` and `AttributedSubstring` are structs - ie. value types

> let range = start..<end 
> attributedString[range].foregroundColor = .red

Does not work. this works only if above declaration is `var attributedString` - variable, not `let attributedString` - constant.

> let substring = attributedString[nsRange] 
> substring.foregroundColor =
> .red

Does not work. this works only if `var substring`  - variable

and now

```
attributedString[nsRange].foregroundColor = .red
```

this does not work because in-line return of subscript is constant, same as `let`

Comment: Well, I profusely apologize for mixing up a `let` and a `var` in my sample code. That being said, this doesn't answer the question. Changing `let` to `var` makes work what I already had working, but it doesn't make `attributedString[nsRange].foregroundColor = .red` work. Is there any way to tell it to return a `var` value from a subscript? Or is that not possible?

Comment: What would be the reason for that? The returned value is destroyed right after end of call line. Or did you expect it updated original attributed string? If yes - then it is wrong - returned substring is not a reference, just copied value. In shot, no - it is not possible in that way.

Comment: What would be the reason? It makes logical sense, this is literally the example on the Swift website: `var numberOfLegs = ["spider": 8, "ant": 6, "cat": 4]; numberOfLegs["bird"] = 2`. `numberOfLegs`'s subscript updates the original value, and subscripting an AttributedString with a `Range<AttributedString.Index>` updates the original string(`var str = AttributedString("..."); str[start..<end].foregroundColor = .red`), so why wouldn't an exension that I write that merely converts an NSRange to a Range<AttributedString.Index> be able to change the original value?

Comment: Why isn't this in-line return constant? `var attributedString = AttributedString("The first month of your subscription is free."); let range = attributedString.range(of: "free")!; attributedString[range].foregroundColor = .green`. Is this using some other mechanism to make this work?